# Need help coming up with formula to count and concatenate specific things

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, microsoft-excel, concatenate

Though I'm not the best at Excel/Google Sheets (this is Sheets specifically), I'm usually able to figure out how to do the things I need. However, this one is stumping me.

Here is a screenshot of my example table (this is mock data).

[image]

The output I need would look like this (using the first three data rows as an example):

**"Chicken nuggets are bad. (n=3; ABC123, DEF456, GHI789)"**

Basically, I need a count of each person that gave that specific feedback, as well as a list of their ID's.

I'm guessing this is possible somehow, but I've tried searching for answers with no luck. Maybe I'm not using the right search terms. Can anyone provide some insight?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!

Please try

```
=IF(A2="","",A2 & TEXTJOIN(";",1," (n=" & IFERROR(MATCH("*",A3:A,0),1),OFFSET(A2,0,1,IFERROR(MATCH("*",A3:A,0),1),1)) & ")")
```